# What reasons could there be for a 64-bit (X86-64) CPU being reported as a 32-bit (i686) in /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit, 32-vs-64-bit, intel-atom

According to [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/59683/intel-atom-processor-d2700-1m-cache-2-13-ghz.html) *(search for "Intel® 64")* I have a 64-bit CPU, but when I check `/proc/cpuinfo` there is no [lm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode) flag.

When I look up the [AD2700-ITX motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/AD2700-ITX/) it says `Due to lack of Intel® 64-bit VGA driver support, this motherboard does not support 64-bit OS`. So is it the motherboard that removes the lm flag?

`/proc/cpuinfo` output for one of the cores:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 54
model name      : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D2700   @ 2.13GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x109
cpu MHz         : 2133.283
cache size      : 512 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 10
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 ss
se3 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm dtherm arat
bugs            :
bogomips        : 4266.53
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Moved here from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104130/what-reasons-could-there-be-for-a-64-bit-x86-64-cpu-being-reported-as-a-32-bit) because it apparently was a [superuser](https://superuser.com/) question...

Comment: Yes, the CPU itself has "Intel 64" support, but for full 64bit support but chipset and BIOS also have to support it to make use of it. Read this for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom#Intel_64_software_support

Comment: @Robert Can you post that as a answer so I can accept it and give you points :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU [Intel Atom D2700](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/59683/intel-atom-processor-d2700-1m-cache-2-13-ghz.html) has support for "Intel 64", however the CPU alone is not sufficient according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom#Intel_64_software_support) to execute 64bit commands on it:

> Intel states the Atom supports 64-bit operation only "with a
> processor, chipset, BIOS" that all support Intel 64. Those Atom
> systems not supporting all of these cannot enable Intel 64.[26] As a
> result, the ability of an Atom-based system to run 64-bit versions of
> operating systems such as Ubuntu or Debian GNU/Linux may vary from one
> motherboard to another.